# vertical / horizontal alignment without top left transform on element with uknown width / height

Tags: html, css

How can i vertically / horizontally align this item with auto generated width / height without using the classic top:50% left:50% transform: translate(-50%,-50%)

**css setup without alignments**

```
#container {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background-color: lightblue;
```

}

```
#myImage {
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-height: 100px;
max-width: 200px;
```

}

Comment: Can we see the aforementioned jsFiddle? On quick glance, you are using floats alongside flex. I don't think you want to be doing that.

Comment: totally forgot to link it :D it's there now. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: "display: absolute;" is invalid; may be you ment "position:absolute; " ?

Comment: You can use `display: table-cell`, [check it](http://jsfiddle.net/dLLan/30/).

Comment: wops, ment to write position, and adding this to the fiddle causes the same problem, - the thing is if i remove it from my site the picture stretches when display: flex which i think i need for justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but this is the image with no fixed height or width set in the CSS. I assume from your OP that you want is centered as such - so if the image dimensions changed it will stay centralized along both axis.

Note the only limitations you face are those older browsers that don't support flex. If that's a problem you can use `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` to good effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/dLLan/29/

css:

```
#container {
 width: 250px;
 max-height: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: lightblue;
 }

#myImage {
 //removed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```css
#helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align:center;
}

#myImage {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="helper"></div>
  <img id="myImage" src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/hirethings/photo/7250/images/thumbnail.jpg?1274508483" />
</div>
```

Comment: what about the horizontal alignment then ?

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox should be fine here depending on your Browser support requirements.

There is no need to position the image...the flex will do that.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.large {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.myImage {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='myImage' src='http://s3.amazonaws.com/hirethings/photo/7250/images/thumbnail.jpg?1274508483' />
</div>

<div class='container large'>
  <img class='myImage' src='http://lorempixel.com/image_output/food-q-c-250-160-5.jpg' />
</div>
```